# How To Make a lot of Imageviews Visible Using for Loop In Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, arrays, imageview

I declared a bunch of Imageview in my code, but when I want to change property of them, it doesn't work at all.

I have already tried to declare it in separated sentences but it doesn't work.

```
int NumberOfMedals= UserData.getInt("USRNBRFMDLS",5);

ImageView[] Medals=new ImageView[] {findViewById(R.id.Main_M1_Img) , findViewById(R.id.Main_M2_Img),
            findViewById(R.id.Main_M3_Img) , findViewById(R.id.Main_M4_Img) , findViewById(R.id.Main_M5_Img) ,
            findViewById(R.id.Main_M6_Img) , findViewById(R.id.Main_M7_Img) , findViewById(R.id.Main_M8_Img) ,
            findViewById(R.id.Main_M9_Img) , findViewById(R.id.Main_M10_Img) , findViewById(R.id.Main_M11_Img)};

int aux;
for (aux=NumberOfMedals; aux==0; aux--){
    Medals[aux].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

I will really thank you, if help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop is wrong, change it to this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Medals.length; i++){
    Medals[i].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Comment: If your app does not crash set them to visible  at first and check if they are visible.

Comment: At the first  all of 11 images are invisible and I want make some of them visible using a loop. (i.e. one to five)

Comment: I said that if by "not working" you mean that the app does not crash but it just does not make the buttons visible, try to start your app with the buttons visible and check if they are really visible.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Problem of my code was Aux==0. and also my Image files was crashed!